# Is the maximum audible noise from power supplies regulated in Europe?

Tags: switch-mode-power-supply, safety, production, regulations, acoustic-noise

Power supplies make sometimes a lot noise in the range of kHz. Is there a regulation for the maximum allowed noise emission for consumer electronics on the European market?

Is there a regulation which would protect customers who buy an alarm clock, but can not sleep anymore, because it chirps loud?

**Where can I look up, which sound profile a device for the European market may emit?**

So far I found only the German "Technische Anleitung zum Schutz gegen Lärm – TA Lärm" and [The Outdoor Noise Directive 2000/14/EC (OND)](http://ec.europa.eu/growth/sectors/mechanical-engineering/noise-emissions/).

Comment: Have designed several power supplies and put them on the European market but never ran into any requirements for audible noise. It is however annoying AF with squeaking and beeping consumer devices.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This would depend on your device. The [low voltage directive](http://eur-lex.europa.eu/legal-content/EN/TXT/HTML/?uri=CELEX:32014L0035&from=EN) most likely applies to your case (pretty much anything that plugs in at home) and so you would adopt one of the [harmonized standards](https://ec.europa.eu/growth/single-market/european-standards/harmonised-standards/low-voltage_en) to establish your product's safety. The applicable standard might define acoustic hazards and limits. For example, audio/video/IT devices would fall under EN 62368-1:2014, where the hazards related to acoustic energy are addressed in clause 10.6. But you'll want to identify the appropriate standard for your particular device and then look there to see if any acoustic hazards are identified, and what is required in response.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I am aware of, there is no requirement for noise of electronic devices per se. But there are regulations of noise levels at various work environments. I.e. if you want to sell your devices for a specific environment, you have to ensure that its noise level is below the one specified for that environment. I don't think I have seen any such noise level regulation for home environments, but I might be mistaken.

Comment: Do you know the name of any regulation, which denies loud power supplies in work environments? I found only the regulations in my question and these address rather loud workshop conditions, where ear protection is needed. Not the office, or hospital where high concentration and silence is crucial.

Comment: I don't know regulations per se, but SUVA (the Swiss work accident insurance) has a small brochure about noise: https://www.suva.ch/material/dokumentationen/belaestigender%20laerm%20am%20arbeitsplatz (see page 17ff). It contains some references to regulations at the end. HTH

Comment: The mentioned page in the Swiss brochure is very informative. The list of regulations include `DIN EN 29295` "Acoustics; measurement of high-frequency noise emitted by computer and business equipment" how to measure noise of devices in the office `ISO 9295:1989`. I will have to read the references now.